# RSS Reader that supports secure feeds?

Tags: rss, ntlm

Does there exist an RSS reader that supports secure (NTLM + HTTPS) feeds?

I've tried RSS Demon, with no luck.

Comment: Rss bandit is a windows rss reader, not android. If you are looking for android, what exactly do you mean by secure? https, or feeds that require a username and password?

Comment: my bad, that should have said demon ;)  fixed!

it requires a username and password

Comment: Have you tried using the http:// user:pass@www.example.com/ syntax?

Comment: @B Mitch:  unfortunately that won't work either as the feed requires SSL

Comment: https:// user:pass@www.example.com would give you ssl support and allow you to pass the username/password. If this doesn't work, then what exactly type of authentication is used?

Comment: I also looked at Rss Demon, and according to its features, both the lite and paid versions support authentication. - "HTTP-Auth/Password: for protected feed, user now can enter a http auth and password"

Comment: it uses windows authentication

Comment: @Ryan:  RSS Demon does let me put in a user name and password, i've verified they are correct, but it doesn't seem to actually be sending them to the server.

Comment: try the user/pass in the url, if that doesnt work, then it may be some issue with the app, and you should contact the app developer.

Comment: no dice :(  it seems it only to do basic http authentication, which the server doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

so it turns out android as an operating system doesn't support anything other the basic http authentication!  so there won't be any readers out there that can support this :(

Comment: The browser does not support NTLM currently. I have read, but do not know 100%, that NTLM is supported in android 3.1

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4962

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4962#c247 as I said, 3.1 adds support for it in the browser. NTLM would have to be implemented by the developer, until there is built-in support in the SDK (3.1).

Comment: sadly my device isn't 3.1, it's 2.2